# Why lambda function fetches data from dict.items() and a list of tuples differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
atomicNumber = {'Rubidium(Rb)':37, 'Lithium(Li)': 2, 'Argon(Ar)': 18 ,'Sodium(Na)': 11, 'Potassium(K)':19, 'Hydrogen(H)': 1,}
sort_atomicNumber = dict(sorted(atomicNumber.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]))
print(sort_atomicNumber)
```

I am trying to sort the dictionary w.r.t the keys. If I use the lambda expression the way I used above, sorting works. But here I am confused when I used notation x[0]. Shouldn't that be x[0][0] in-order to sort by key name???

I can see that the dict_view returned by dict.items() looks similar to list of tuples, so why when sorting x[0] returned the string object and in case of below list of tuple 'AtmNum' lambda returned a tuple?

```
dict_items([('Rubidium(Rb)', 37), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Sodium(Na)', 11), ('Potassium(K)', 19), ('Hydrogen(H)', 1)])

AtmNum = [('Rubidium(Rb)', 37), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Sodium(Na)', 11), ('Potassium(K)', 19), ('Hydrogen(H)', 1)]
f = lambda x:x[0]
print(f(AtmNum))
```

OUTPUT:
('Rubidium(Rb)', 37)

Comment: Why are you converting to `dict` after sorting? `sort_atomicNumber = dict(sorted(...))` now it is unsorted again

Comment: @Ralf, with converting it into a dict I would get:
    [('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Hydrogen(H)', 1), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Potassium(K)', 19), 
    ('Rubidium(Rb)', 37), ('Sodium(Na)', 11)]

and I want it to be a dictionary with sorted by keys.
    {'Argon(Ar)': 18, 'Hydrogen(H)': 1, 'Lithium(Li)': 2, 'Potassium(K)': 19, 
    'Rubidium(Rb)': 37, 'Sodium(Na)': 11}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
sort_atomicNumber = dict(sorted(atomicNumber.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]))
```

the x in your lambda that serves as a sorting key is a `(key, value)` tuple generated by `.items()`. As you noticed in your experiment, `.items()` generates an (iterable) list of those tuples, `sorted` iterates through the list and check order of each of element by applying the lambda to it. Thus in your first example lambda refers to an element of an iterable created with `.items()`.

As opposed to that, in the second example:

```
AtmNum = [('Rubidium(Rb)', 37), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Sodium(Na)', 11), ('Potassium(K)', 19), ('Hydrogen(H)', 1)]
f = lambda x:x[0]
print(f(AtmNum))
```

`x` is now the whole list, so reasonably `x[0]` refers to its first element.

Answer (score 2):

`atomicNumber.items()` generates `tuple`s, so for example, in the first iteration, the `tuple` generated is `('Rubidium(Rb)', 37)` (referenced by `x`), so, `x[0]` would be the key, and `x[1]` would be the value.

When you tried to imitate it, you passed the `dict_items` as an argument to the `lambda` function, while in the `sorted` function, the `tuple`s that are inside the `dict_items` are the ones being passed to the `lambda` function. So, the correct imitation would be something like:

```
AtmNum = [('Rubidium(Rb)', 37), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Sodium(Na)', 11), ('Potassium(K)', 19), ('Hydrogen(H)', 1)]
f = lambda x:x[0]
print(f(AtmNum[0]))  #  passing the first tuple
```

Output:

```
Rubidium(Rb)
```

Comment: but atomicNumber.items() generated a list which contain a tuples (key,val)... isn't it much like [(k1, v1), (k2,v3, (k3,v3).....] ? and x[0] should give us first tuple (k1,v1) !!

Comment: @AdarshNamdev I just added more explanations about what's being passed to the lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you converting to `dict` after sorting? `sort_atomicNumber = dict(sorted(...))` causes the data to be unsorted again.

You can use `collection.OrderedDict` instead:

```
import collections
data = {
    'Rubidium(Rb)': 37,
    'Lithium(Li)': 2,
    'Argon(Ar)': 18,
    'Sodium(Na)': 11,
    'Potassium(K)': 19,
    'Hydrogen(H)': 1,
}

sorted_by_key = collections.OrderedDict(
    sorted(data.items()))
print(sorted_by_key)

sorted_by_val = collections.OrderedDict(
    sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(sorted_by_val)
```

The output is

```
OrderedDict([('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Hydrogen(H)', 1), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Potassium(K)', 19), ('Rubidium(Rb)', 37), ('Sodium(Na)', 11)])
OrderedDict([('Hydrogen(H)', 1), ('Lithium(Li)', 2), ('Sodium(Na)', 11), ('Argon(Ar)', 18), ('Potassium(K)', 19), ('Rubidium(Rb)', 37)])
```

You don't need to use `key=lambda...` for `sorted()` when you wish to sort by key because the data returned by `dict.items()` already contains the keys at the front.

Comment: thanks @Ralf for suggesting a new cool thing. So here, the dictionary got sorted w.r.t keys what if I need to sort it w.r.t values ...for eg. {'Hydrogen': 1, 'Lithium': 2. 'Sodium': 11.....}

Answer (score 1):

`dict` type may not preserve item order at all. You should not convert list of tuples to `dict` after sorting. (If you need a dict style structure, look at `collections.OrderedDict`).

Lambda in `sorted` getting each element of sortable sequance and return sorting key (comparable value)  . In this case `items()` return "list of tuples" (key, value) in dict and `lambda x:x[0]` returns first element (key) of each pair.